# phonegap geolocation, Code 3 - timeout expired keeps popping up on some Android Devices

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I am using the PhoneGap API for geolocation. I have set the enableHighAccuracy Option to "true". Code 3, time out expired option keeps popping up, but only on some android devices and more than once while using the application.

Please help me... Why is this so that it fails only on some android devices. If I set the accuracy  to false, how much difference will I get in retrieving the coordinates...

Answer (score 10):

Managed to resolve my issue with the code below:

```
var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy:true};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

It seems that samsung galaxy phones do not like to cache the gps location.

Comment: @GeorgeL: sir i have tried not properly working for me i got message: "Timeout expired" error in console tell me how to fix?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here how to fix the issue:

1. Add a timeout and set enableHighAccuracy:

   ```
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
   ```

   In certain emulators you need to set enableHighAccuracy to false, so try that if still doesn't work.
2. In Android, the emulator don’t read GPS values, so we need to send them via command line. We need to start a telnet session in the port that the emulator is running (you can check the port in the emulator window title, the number at the beginning, in my case 5554):

   ```
   telnet localhost 5554
   ```

And then run the command

```
    geo fix -122.4 37.78
```

If you close the app you need to re-send the geolocation, so if it doesn’t work, just run the `geo fix` command just after opening the app, before the timeout event fires.

Comment: Bigger "timeout" and "enableHighAccuracy" solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue. Setting `enableHighAccuracy` to `false` and restart emulator (from Android SDK) fixes my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same error on Samsung Galaxy Note II (Android 4.1.1). For some reason, when 'Use wireless networks' under the Location settings is on it works, but if it's off it gets the code 3 error. It didn't happen on Nexus 7 (4.2.2).

Comment: Thanks, it solve my problem which freaking me out. It is because the device doesnt use high acurracy automatically sometime and we need to set it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, found same problem here.  Wish there were a better way around it than asking users to kindly change their GPS settings.
Samsung Galaxy III

(works when "use wireless networks to find position" fails without this option)