# Can not call geolocation plugin in Android platform

Tags: android, geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst

We use Worklight 6.2 or MobileFirst Foundation 7.0 and want to use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition to get the GPS position, but there is not any response and no error, does anyone know why?

It works on older versions.

Comment: Provide a demo application where this is failing for you, and remember that you must add these permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml:  android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" and android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION".

Comment: Idan, it's in the title of the Q :)

Comment: Right, i saw it and then forgot I saw it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not getting not success nor failure, and since you did not supply your implementation, I am left in thinking that you did not implement it correctly.

I tested the below in the Android Emulator in MFPF 7.0, and it worked:

**common\main.js:**

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
}

function success(pos) {
     var crd = pos.coords;
      alert('Your current position is:' + crd.latitude + " " + crd.longitude + " " + crd.accuracy);
}

function error(err) {
      alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
}
```

And of course also added the following two permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

---

If you're also testing in the emulator and getting a timeout, either increase the timeout value or force the location change in the DDMS view in Eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152773/1530814

Comment: Hi Idan, Thank you very much. Yes I forgot to add the permissions to the configure file. The new Cordova document is very poor, lost the important configuration guidance.

Comment: Another comments, why I can not find any geolocaiton classes in the cordova.jar file in Android Project lib directory?